# Server key refused. No authentication methods available

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, key

We had created a ppk files using putty gen and logged in in out ubuntu instance of ec2. the wifi had a drop and we suddenly started getting this error for "Server key refused. No authentication methods available ". Now even if i make a new ppk file and use in putty, the error is the same.

Can somebody please suggest a way out
we are stuck!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the EBS is instance-backed I would try to generate an AMI for the EC2 instance (in the Web Console right click on your instance) and start a new instance with a private key that you have access to. Once logged in you can try to change your auth credentials again.